# Handle Multiple Checkboxes with a Single Serverside Variable

Tags: python, html, checkbox

I have the following HTML code:

```
<form method="post">
              <h5>Sports you play:</h5>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played" value="basketball"> basketball<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played" value="football"> football<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played" value="baseball"> baseball<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played" value="soccer"> tennis<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played" value="mma"> MMA<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played" value="hockey"> hockey<br>

                <br> 

                    <input class="btn" type="submit">

</form>
```

And then ideally I would like to have the following python serverside code:

```
class MyHandler(ParentHandler):
    def post(self):
        sports_played = self.request.get('sports_played')
        #sports_played is a list or array of all the selected checkboxes that I can iterate through
```

I tried doing this by making the HTML sports_played name and array, sports_played[], but that didn't do anything and right now it just always returns the first selected item.

Is this possible?  Really I just don't want to have to do a self.request.get('HTML_item') for each and every checkbox incase I need to alter the HTML I don't want to have to change the python.

Thanks!

Comment: What server-side framework are you using?

Comment: Yes I should've included that, I'm using webapp2 (http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/)

Comment: For a [tag:nodejs] [tag:express] specific answer to this, see here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584428/checkbox-array-returns-the-last-checked-value-in-nodejs-not-whole-array/65597423#65597423

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is shown in the [webapp2 docs for the request object](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#get-data):

```
self.request.get('sports_played', allow_multiple=True)
```

Alternatively you can use

```
self.request.POST.getall('sports_played')
```

Comment: okay nice, I was looking for some change on the HTML side but I should've looked at the framework.  That got it working although according to the docs the allow_multiple param is deprecated and it didn't work for me.

Comment: also it is get_all() not getall()

Answer (score 6):

Although this answer **is not related to this question**, but it may help all the **django** developers who is walking here and there.

In **Django** `request.POST` is a `QueryDict` object. So you can get all the values as list by following way

```
request.POST.getlist('sports_played')
```

**N.B: This only works in Django**

Answer (score 5):

The name of the inputs should have `[]` at the end so that they are set to the server as an array.  Right now, your multiple checkboxes are being sent to the server as many variables with the same name, so only one is recognized.  It should look like this:

```
<form method="post">
              <h5>Sports you play:</h5>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played[]" value="basketball"> basketball<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played[]" value="football"> football<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played[]" value="baseball"> baseball<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played[]" value="soccer"> tennis<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played[]" value="mma"> MMA<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="sports_played[]" value="hockey"> hockey<br>

                <br> 

                    <input class="btn" type="submit">

</form>
```

Now, if you select more than one, the values will be sent as an array.

Comment: This is a PHP specific answer, the question is about a Python web framework. In HTML forms, you don't need the `[]` for multiple inputs. It is only in PHP that this is needed to get the framework to recognise multiple inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If using Flask, the solution is very similar to the Django and webapp2 solution.
You can get a list with the values of all the checkboxes with:

```
selections = request.form.getlist('sports_played')
```

There is a related Flask specific question with a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344797/how-create-an-array-with-checkboxes-in-flask), but the correct answer there has never been accepted.