# How create an array with checkboxes in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm starting in flask, so i have many questions about it. And one of them is how to create an array based on name of the checkbox input?
In other words, python will follow the logic: for each of type "checkbox", which ones were filled?

I have those codes:
index.html

```
{% block content %}


<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="card" style="margin:50px 0">
    <div class="card-header"><b>Letters</b></div>

    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">A
    <label class="switch ">
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" class="danger">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">B
    <label class="switch ">
    <input type="checkbox" name="B" class="danger">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">C
    <label class="switch ">
    <input type="checkbox" name="C" class="danger">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</div>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

And funcs.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '0000'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When the user has checked boxes named "A" and "C", python creates an array and display the array shortly afterwards when the user submit.

```
checked = ["A", "C"]
```

Answer (score 15):

Your HTML is heading in the right direction, but a few minor changes for Flask to handle this effectively.

First, set the current value of the  `name` attribute to the `value` attribute. This will determine values Flask pulls during the form post. Secondly, set the `name` attribute to have a common value.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="A" class="danger" name='my_checkbox'>
<input type="checkbox" value="B" class="danger" name='my_checkbox'>
<input type="checkbox" value="C" class="danger" name='my_checkbox'>
```

After the HTML is configured as such, you can use the `getlist` method from Flask's request module.

```
print(request.form.getlist('my_checkbox'))
>>> ['A', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

When a POST request is sent to the flask server you can get form contents from `request.form`. which is a dictionary based off of the POST request.

With check boxes, if the box is ticked the input `name` in `<input type="checkbox" name="A" class="danger">` would be in this dictionary. Therefore you can check for the check box like so:

```
if "A" in request.form:
    checked.append("A")  # You can of course append any arbitrary value
```